# Using a key to authorise creation of model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, key

I am unsure if my logic is correct in the following scenario, maybe its not even a best practice or there could be a simpler way. Also i am unsure how to set up my code so if anyone has any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Ok so I have two models

```
class MiniLeague < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :league_name, :team_id, :league_key

  has_many :teams
end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :team_name, :user_id, :mini_league_id, :key

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mini_leagues
end
```

When creating a a mini-league a random number is generated (key) so that only teams with that key can join that league. The key will be passed on to users who want to join that specific mini league.

the part i am a little stuck on is what to do when adding a team to a league, so far my thinking is when creating a team have a field to add this key which is then saved to the model (or if the team is already created update with the key). So now my team model has a team name and a key.

Any suggestions on how to go about comparing the two keys so that only authorised teams can join the mini league. or would you approach this differently? I realise this can be a large answer, but am happy to take some pointers so that i can then go find the resources on how to do something like this

Thanks

EDIT

Would i be able to do something like so in the team controller

```
Team Controller

def create
  if params[:key] && params[:mini_league_id] == params[:mini_league][:league_key] && params[:mini_league][:league_id]
  @team = Team.create(params[:team])
  else
  render :new, notice: "invalid key"
  end
 end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach is to create a new model to represent the connection between Team and MiniLeague.

In fact, what needs to be validated is that connection. In addition, I guess that at least theoretically a Team could abandoned / been ejected from a MiniLeague; in that case what you are destroying is the connection between both models.

Assuming that approach you can check the key with a custom validator in the new Model.

So, if we call the new model let's say Enrollment:

In app/models/team.rb:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :team_name, :user_id, :key

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :mini_leagues, through: enrollments
end
```

In app/models/mini_league.rb:

```
class MiniLeague < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :league_name, :league_key

  has_many :teams, through: enrollments
end
```

In app/models/enrollment.rb:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :team_id, :mini_league_id

    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :mini_league

    validate :valid_key?

    protected
    def valid_key?
      errors.add(:base, "Invalid key") unless team.key == mini_league.league_key
    end
end
```

Now, the Enrollment controller will be the responsible for creating the connection between a Team and a MiniLeague, and not the Team controller.

So your controller is just responsible for triggering the 'save' method, which will be valid or invalid depending on the model logic, as it should be (app/controllers/enrollments_controller.rb):

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    @enrollemnt = Enrollment.new(params[:enrollment])

    if @enrollment.save
      # success, go on with the application flow
    else
      # error, automanaged for custom model validator if comes from a non valid league key, show the form again
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Now if you want to show the custom error message that we have created in the custom validator the easy way is to create a partial to be inserted in your new Team form:

in your app/views/enrollments/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@enrollment) do |f| %>  
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @enrollment %> 

  # and then the rest of your form
  ...
```

and in app/views/shared/error_messages:

```
<% if target.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
  <h2><%= pluralize(target.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% target.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

The target.errors contains the array of errors, including our custom validator one, and the iteration through the full_messages collection will show the "Invalid key" message.

**To sum up**

After creating a new Enrollment, both the associated Team and MiniLeague will response to:

```
my_team.mini_leagues
```

and to

```
my_mini_league.teams
```

Comment: hi @Galen, thanks that does help, quick question, in my else statement do i just call the valid_key? method, because at the moment i get You need to supply at least one validation error message hen rendering the page

Comment: i changed validates to validate

Comment: You are right, it is validate, not validates. I have also expand the explanation to include how to show the custom validation error message, just in case.

Comment: thanks that makes sense, but still getting undefined local variable or method `mini_league

Comment: Sorry @Richlewis, I didn't notice that the Team has_many MiniLeagues... I think that the best way to go is to create a new model, let's say Enrollment, to represent the 'join', I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Please note also that I have deleted the 'team_id' and 'mini_league_id' from the list of attributes in MiniLeague and Team models, respectively. Even with your original approach the association was already a has_many/has_many, and therefore a Team could not have a 'mini_league_id' attribute (same for MiniLeague)